# How to root project in valid location in InetlliJ?

Tags: java, python, intellij-idea, plugins

Error Message:

```
PLUGIN is disabled: PLUGIN has detected that the project is not rooted in a WORKSPACE.
Make sure your project root is located where your packageInfo file is.
```

How to fix this error in IntelliJ ?

Comment: What plugins produces this message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that one has to right click on the project (after following the instructions to rename the Project), then choose Refactor -> Move to relocate project to the new location. I didn't find any solution to rename and move a project at once.